# Email server with automatic + sign aliases?

Tags: email, alias

Is there currently a Linux email server that will allow me to replicate how Gmail or Outlook allow aliases.

i.e. with Hotmail (which is now Outlook) or Gmail I can sign up on a site and use myname+askubuntu@outlook.com and it will come to the myname@outlook.com account without first having to set up an alias.

Comment: The plus sign `+` can be part of any email address' [local part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Local_part). Automatically disposing seems something Hotmail specific to me that Gmail copied (or vv.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typically called “plus addressing”. Most email servers can do it and were already doing it before GMail and Hotmail existed and copied that feature.

With Postfix, set [`recipient_delimiter` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter). This is in the default configuration as shipped by some distributions such as Debian and Ubuntu.

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

With Exim, [set a local part in `/etc/exim.conf`](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_default_configuration_file.html#SECID55):

```
local_part_suffix = +* : -*
local_part_suffix_optional
```

The old [Email addressing FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/mail/addressing/) discusses some older MTAs including Sendmail and Qmail.